# Class and selector matching in CSS/Javascript/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to match a JQuery CSS call (modifying CSS so that I can use a variable) with some Javascript div/classes. I can't use "id" because there are many of these instances in a loop. Edit: it is still not quite working and I suspect I need a little more detail here.

The relevant piece of the CSS (there are other transform lines, not shown here):

```
.thermometer .circle {
    position: absolute;
    ...

.pie {
    position: absolute;
    ...
}

.hold {
    position: absolute;
    ...
    clip: rect(0px, 26px, 26px, 13px);
}

.pieSlice1 .pie {
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(60deg);
    transform:rotate(60deg);
}
```

In a JST EJS file:

```
 <div class="thermometer">
   <div class="circle <%= this.presenter.newColor(nutrient) %>">
     <div class="pieSlice1 hold">
       <div class="pie"></div>
         <% $(".pieSlice1.hold .pie").css({'-webkit-transform': 'rot
ate(22deg)'}); %>
```

I've removed the space between "pieSlice1" and "hold", but do I need any of the other classes in order to match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an intersection, just write the selectors together without spaces in between.

```
$(".pieSlice1.hold .pie").css({'-webkit-transform': 'rot
ate(22deg)'});
```

When we include space, it looks for descendants...

Another option is:

```
$(".pieSlice1").filter(".hold .pie").css({'-webkit-transform': 'rot
ate(22deg)'});
```

Comment: Please have a quick second look. I suspect I am still not fully there.

Comment: That should work..,If it does not , try `.thermometer .pieSlice1.hold .pie`

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
.pieSlice1.hold .pie
```

without any space between `.pieSlice1` and `.hold`

Comment: thanks, @keune. Please take a look if you get a chance- I added a bit more. I suspect it i s not quite right.

Comment: the selector syntax and the css property you're trying to add is right. If it's not working, there should be some other problem.

Comment: thanks. I am not sure how to find the other problem. I suspect I need to learn more about javascript debugging, to find out why the match isn't happening. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since `.pieSlice1` and `.hold` are both classes on the same element, you need to chain them:

```
.pieSlice1.hold .pie
```

Note how there's no space between `.pieSlice1` and `.hold` – that means it will match an element with the class `.pie` which is a descendant of an element that has *both* `.pieSlice1` and `.hold` classes.

Whereas with what you have now...

```
.pieSlice1 .hold .pie
```

That would match an element with the class `.pie` which is a descendant of an element with the class `.hold`, which *itself* is a descendant of an element with the class `.pieSlice1`.

Comment: #daGUY, thanks so much. Please take another look at the edit - I suspect I still don't have it quite right.